# Reading data from file and adding it to database without adding the same values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, file

So I have this program that reads the text file and add its content to my database. I have no problem here. But when new content is added to file and the program is run again, all the values are stored in the database from the beginning, but i just want the new content to be added on top when i run the program for the second time. How can I do this, here is my code. Thanks in advance!!

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {

    PreparedStatement preparedstatement = null;


    try{
        String read=null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patientlist.txt")); 
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
            name=splited[0];
            age=splited[1];
            height=splited[2];
            weight=splited[3];      
            addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);}
        if (connection != null)
        try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore){} 
    }


    public static void addpatient(Connection connection, PreparedStatement preparedstatement, String name, String age, String height, String weight) throws SQLException{
    preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into allpatients(name, age, height, weight) values(?,?,?,?)");
    preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
    preparedstatement.setString(2, age);
    preparedstatement.setString(3, height);
    preparedstatement.setString(4, weight);
    preparedstatement.executeUpdate();


    }
```

Comment: How about querying the database to check if the record already exists before you insert it?

Comment: And how is that done, I'm not an experienced programmer?

Comment: So your challenge is to detect the existence of previously inserted records?   This isn't a Java question. It's pure SQL, really.   Your answer will look something like "`if not exists (select 1 from allpatients where ....) insert into allpatients values(...)`".

Comment: Is there a UNIQE key? Is name unique? Can you empty your source file after added it in the database? Please consider to adjust indentation in your code to simplify readibility.

Comment: So i won't change my code but enter a statement in sql? I don't know what to write though..

Comment: Hi id is unique, i can delete after i add, but its also auto_increment

Comment: If the text file is only appended to, I would have your app remember the line number last processed. Then only insert the records behind that line. And if that text file is not used for other purposes you could rename it/copy it to backup and empty it after processing.

Comment: Where is id? If you can delete/empty the source file is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes it is appended but how will i make the app to remember the line number?

Comment: I created table with id,name,age,height,weight where id is int primary key auto_increment. How it is solved?

Comment: After your while loop you could delete/empty the source file so the next execution will be clean.

Comment: And what is the delete/empty statement?

Comment: Wouldn't that just add than delete when i just run the program 1 time

Comment: delete/empty your source txt file!

Comment: i add file.delete i added it after while loop. i ran the program 2 times it added the same values again. no use sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!isPatent(connection, preparedstatement, name)) 
    addpatient(connection, preparedstatement, name, age, height, weight);



    public static boolean isPatient(Connection connection,
            PreparedStatement preparedstatement, String name)
            throws SQLException {
        boolean exists = false;
        preparedstatement = connection
                .prepareStatement("select * from allpatients where name = ?");

        preparedstatement.setString(1, name);
        ResultSet rs = preparedstatement.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            exists = true;
        }
        rs.close();
        return exists;
    }
```

Comment: True mauretto. Think that it's the problem he wants to solve.